# Value (number) is different from the MongoDB to the react client async call

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

**Problem**:

An entire field of my MongoDB's collections' is not transmitted correctly from the db to the react client. For an exemple, the first element of this field is `tweet_id: 1537466989966413825` in my DB. It becomes `tweet_id: 1537466989966413800` when I fetch from my client.

**My steps**

I pull my data from the MongoDB using their App services' `function` like that:

```
exports = function(){
  var collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("meme_news").collection("news");
  return collection.find({});
};
```

When I press the Run button of their built-in terminal, the correct data is displayed.

On my react's application, I perform the fetch like that:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {

    let getAllData = await user.functions.getAllData();
    // all these data are wrong 
    let tweetId = getAllData
    .map((ele) => {
      return ele.tweet_id;
    })

    let tweetIdFirstEle = tweetId[0];
    // this return 1537466989966413800
    // It should return 1537466989966413825

  };
```

Why is my async/await altering my Mongodb data? I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your comment - can you develop?

Comment: JS can not represent that number to that accuracy. What you see is your float's accuracy being capped at 53 bits. I'd suggest using a string or bigint but I don't know enough about mongo to tell you how to change the values type "mid flight" so to say, on the way from/to the DB.

Comment: But I need the exact value. How do I do that?

Comment: My knowledge of data types is not as expert - but I guess, a quick way to fix this would be to stringify all my numbers?